# How convert simulink files to XML

Tags: java, xml, simulink

I need convert an Simulink file (.mdl) to an XML file, after any searches i'm not found any content to help me with this problem.

You'd know some way or ready solution for this in Java?

Comment: And what will you do with it, after you've converted to XML?

Comment: Good morning Ira, so i will generate the XSD of this XML generated.

Comment: Building an XSD for an XML version of Simulink doesn't seem like an interesting goal.  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Starting in R2008b, you can export an .mdl file to an .xml file using [save_system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/save_system.html),

```
>> save_system('model.mdl', 'model_xml.xml','ExportToXML', true);
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I had not seen his response yesterday. The R2008b it's an independent library in Java ? ...sorry for not understand :/

Comment: I understand your question now.  You need Simulink/MATLAB in order to save the .mdl file to an XML format.  I don't know of any independent Java library that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no easy solution.

However, there are a couple of libraries in Java that apparently can **parse** simulink files.  They should be sufficient to give you an in-memory representation, and you could then use an XML binding to produce passable XML.

Comment: Hi Stephen, i found the SimulinkModelBuilder, this library loads an MDL file and i can access all file contents. What xml library can i use to serialize this object in XML notation ?